# I can't manage to find the JVM(javascript Virtual Machine) as an environment to deploy my solidity smart contract on Remix IDE, Any idea why?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, javascript-vm

[image]
I can't manage to find the JVM(javascript Virtual Machine) as an environment to deploy my solidity smart contract on Remix IDE, Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 `Remix VM` are what you are looking for, they don't need any further setup  since the blockchain runs inside your browser directly.